# Отправить http запрос из виджета android

Tags: java, android, http, android-widgets

Всем доброго вечера. Задача такая: нужно отправить get запрос, а потом ответ вывести на экран виджета android. Вопрос заключается в том, что запрос по каким-то причинам не отправляется. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать ? Сейчас все работает (а вернее не работает) по такой схеме:

Провайдер виджета:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public Widget() {
    InetConn in = new InetConn();
    String tempt = in.getInet();
    Log.d("CREATION", tempt);
  }

}
```

Класс для работы с http:

```
public class InetConn {
//откуда получаем данные
public String USER_URL = "http://test.ru/api.php?query=1";
public String RESULT_OK = "ok";
public String RESULT_SERVER = "server";
public String RESULT_USER_NOT_FOUND = "not_found";
public String RESULT_NETWORK = "network";


public String getInet()
{
    String result = "";
    String url = USER_URL;
    String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();
    int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    if (proxyPort > 0)
    {
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
    }
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {

            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), Charset.forName("CP1251")));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            sb.append('°');
            String answer = sb.toString();
            result = answer;
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Может я тут в чем-то ошибся ? Просто в логах чисто. В манифесте разрешение прописал. Заранее спасибо )
Еще маленький вопросик, получится ли сделать обновление виджета раз в 30 секунд ?

Comment: Возможно надо в сеть в отдельном потоку залезать?..

Comment: Да, так и есть, спасибо !) 
А по поводу обновления каждые 30 секунд, как вы думаете, получится ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Запрос из виджета, так же как и просто из приложения, надо делать в отдельном потоке. Например через `AsyncTask`
2. Обновление можно, по идее, через `AlarmManager` сделать.